# How to play multiple AudioBufferSourceNode synchronized?

Tags: html, web-audio-api

I have multiple audio files that must be played in sync. I have read that Web Audio API is the best solution for this. But, I can't find any document that shows how to achieve this.

Almost all articles I have read do this to start playback.

```
//Let's say I have AudioBufferSourceNode connected to two buffers
var source1, source2;

source1.start(0);
source2.start(0);
```

Shouldn't this cause source2 to start playing slightly later than source1?

Also, what makes the sources stay in sync? I can not find any mention in any documentation that assures that sources are played in sync.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can schedule them slightly in the future.

```
var source1, source2;
var when = context.currentTime + 0.01;

source1.start(when);
source2.start(when);
```

That'll schedule both sounds to play exactly 10ms from the moment you define `when`. It's quick enough that it'll be perceived as immediate, but gives a bit of breathing room for the overhead of actually calling `start` on the first source node.

There are better ways to do this if you have a ton of nodes, but for simple situations, this should be fine.

Comment: Kevin, and will the sources stay in sync? Any info on that? Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, they'll stay in sync. I don't really have any info on it, though. Clock stuff isn't addressed at all in the spec, as far as I can tell.

Comment: FYI, you should probably go ahead and accept Chris's answer below instead of mine.

Answer (score 1):

There is a single clock for the audio context, and the buffer playback is on that clock - so yes, they will stay in sync.

Even calling start(0); start(0); as above will be perfectly synchronized, because start() is setting up a scheduling request on the audio thread, and the actual scheduling of both of those will happen together.  "now" is actually slightly in the future (the audio system latency).

Comment: Oh, that's interesting.

So, no matter how much work I'm doing or how long it takes, any calls to `start(0)` in a given call stack will be scheduled at exactly the same time?

Comment: Hmm, not POSITIVE about that; best to create them with a future start time, as you said.  There might be a non-observable race condition there.  But realistically, if you called start(0);start(0); they'd be in sync.